# Is it possible to use Activex in PHP?

Tags: php, activex

Is it possible to use ActiveX in PHP? I want to use an ActiveX in my server-side PHP code.

---

I'm trying to load an Activex in my PHP code, As I know this can be done with COM function in PHP, so I try to access my methods as below:

```
<?PHP
$active = new COM("sswATL.crypto");
//------------------------

$pass = "pincode";

$ret = $active->init( $pass , $retVal);

if($retVal == 0){ 
   print "Login successfully";
}
elseif($retVal == 4){

   print "Token is not present";
} 
else
{
   $errMsg = "Login failed : "; 
   print $errMsg;
  }
?>
```

but I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception'
with message '<b>Source:</b> Unknown<br/><b>Description:</b> Unknown'
in C:\my\php\file\path.php
Stack trace:
#0 C:\my\php\file\path.php: com->init('pincode', NULL)
#1 {main}
thrown in C:\my\php\file\path.php on line 7
```

init method is declared as:

```
int init(string s,int &num);
```

any ideas?

Comment: You can, but why would you? PHP is primarily targeted at Linux/*nix hosting, while COM is Windows-only. But on Windows, there's ASP and ASP.NET, that's much more COM-friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the COM class for calling ActiveX: http://cn.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php

```
function clsMSWord($Visible = false) { 
    $this->handle = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instanciate Word"); 
    $this->handle->Visible = $Visible; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, then can I call my Activex methods after I load it with COM ? maybe this question does not make any sense to you but I am totally beginner in PHP

Comment: [The PHP COM Manual](http://cn.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php) has a example for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActiveX using [COM functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.com.php)

Good documentation about COM class can be found **[here](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.com.php)**.

Comment: For some COM objects, anyway .. "ActiveX" components often have particular hosting requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, which requirements you are talking about?